# How to emphase some region on a spherical surface

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, transparency, geometry-surface

**Introduction**

I'm trying to emphase some region on a spherical surface saying that this region should be colored as not transparent (alpha = 1.0) and other parts of the sphere should be colored as semi-transparent (alpha = 0.5).

**Problem**

Considering `WAlpha(Data >= DummyValue) = 1.0` and  `WAlpha(Data < DummyValue) = 0.5`, the following command does not work as expected:

```
surf(X, Y, Z, Data, 'AlphaData', WAlpha, 'FaceAlpha', 'interp');
```

It draws all non-selected region as fully-transparent:

[image: Wrong transparency]

**Note**

I have no issue when setting 'FaceAlpha' to scalar value (i.e its not an issue with my graphic card):

```
surf(X, Y, Z, Data, 'AlphaData', WAlpha, 'FaceAlpha', 0.5);
```

[image: Semi transparent everywhere]

**Source code**

Here is the link to the very short and dummy code I created to reproduce the issue: [link](https://gist.github.com/3150662)

Please let me know if you have any other idea for emphasing selected region rather than using transparency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is quick test:

```
%# surface data
Z = membrane;

%# alpha-transparency matrix
A = ones(size(Z))*0.3;          %# transparent by default
A(abs(Z)>0.5) = 1;              %# make certain region opaque

%# plot
figure('Renderer','opengl')
surf(Z, 'AlphaData',A, 'AlphaDataMapping','none', ...
    'FaceAlpha','interp', 'EdgeColor','none')
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yep, guess setting `AlphaDataMapping` to `none` or resetting `Alim` to `[0 1]` ends up the same. Thanks for your help and test case.

Answer (score 1):

Ooops, found it...

One needs to change the `Alim` property on `axes` object because it is *improperly* set to `[min(WAlpha) max(WAlpha)]` when setting `AlphaData` instead of keeping `[0 1]`. So the command is:

```
surf(X, Y, Z, Data, 'AlphaData', WAlpha, 'FaceAlpha', 'interp');
alim([0 1]);
```

Comment: I cannot accept my own answer for 2 days (so I accepted @Amro 's one :p)